# In J2ME Using LWUIT library. How to call another Form?

Tags: java-me, lwuit

How to call another Form? When I used `form.show()` method, component of another form are not displayed.
Example...

FirstForm.java

```
public class FirstForm extends MIDlet implements ActionListener
{
    Form frm_first = new Form("First");
    public Command cmd_Login;
    public void startApp()
    {
        Display.init(this);
        cmd_Login = new Command("Login");
        frm_first.addComponent(cmd_login);
        ......
    }
    public void pauseApp() {}

    public void destroyApp(boolean unconditional) {}

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
    {
        Command cmd = ae.getCommand();
        String strcmdName = cmd.getCommandName();

        if (strcmdName.equals("Login"))
        {
             //how to call Login Form
        }
    }
}
```

Login.java

```
public class Login extends Form implements ActionListener
{
     Form frm_Login = new Form("Login");
     Button btn_Login = new Button("Login");
     public Login()
     {
       ....
      . ....
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First you have to create Form in your class FirstForm. 
Like `Form frm=new Form("First Form");`
then add command your cmd_Login in form like `frm.addCommand(cmd_Login);`
then set command Listener to form `frm.setCommandListener(this);`
& need to be `implements CommandListener` in FirstForm not ActionListener.
then in `public void commandAction(Command c, Displayable d) {` now you have to write code to go second Form.
& One thing i noticed in your Login class, you always extending class Form & also creating Form object in Login class... If you are using extend class Form then dont create Form Object.
Thanks

Comment: Hey sajid thanks for replay yaar.In login form its necessary to define all defination of component in login constructor. If not what is solution.plz give some example.  thank u very much

Comment: Thanks u Sajid. hav a great day

Answer (score 1):

simply use

```
new Login().show();
```

Comment: In login form its necessary to define all defination of component in login constructor. If not what is solution.plz give some example.  thank u very much

Answer (score 0):

The best way I have found to call a form from within another, after implementing a listener is to use this: `showForm("name of Form", null);`

Another way to call another form, but from within a component action is this: `showContainer("name of Form",c, null);`

Answer (score 0):

This line is invoked before Display.init(this); Hence you get an exception and nothing works.

```
Form frm_first = new Form("First");
```

Move the initialization code after the `Display.init(this)` code.